# How can I exclude NA values when visualizing data in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use ggplot to visualize the data in R using a bar chart. I have NA values that I want to ignore without deleting any rows or columns. I tried using `na.rm = TRUE`  but it is not working. Is this correct? If not how can I do it?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Flavours, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_bar() + labs(y = "Here is a label", title = "Here is the title" ) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Take `na.rm = TRUE` out of `aes` and put it inside `geom_bar`

Comment: I tried this as well, but it didn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this filter in your data.

The *!=* symbol it is used to mute rows with hsa **NAs** as a condition

```
ggplot(data %>% filter(!is.na(Flavours), aes(x = Flavours)) + 
geom_bar() + 
labs(y = "Here is a label", title = "Here is the title" ) + 
theme_bw()
```

To use the pipe *%>%* will need install the package **dplyr**

Comment: I tried this and I got this error (I use  (Dealers is instead of Flavours)...         Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..2 = aes(x = Dealer)`.
Caused by error in `vec_size()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <uneval> object.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example following your original code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(x = c("A","B","C","D",NA, "F", "G", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"L"),
                   y = c(NA, 10, 12, NA, 32, 21, NA, 35, NA, 32, 21, NA, 35))


ggplot(data, aes(y, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_bar() + labs(y = "Here is a label", title = "Here is the title" ) +
  theme_bw()
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]